# Is there a reliable way to find Zephyrite lockpicks?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I want to keep opening all those locked chests around Dry Top, but I'm all out of lockpicks! Buying more costs geodes that I'd rather spend on other things, and sifting through sand has a ridiculously low chance of yielding one.

Am I getting too greedy here, or is there some trick that I'm missing?

Comment: Can't remember off the top of my head which ones, but I believe some of the early Season 2 Living Story instances reward you with a few lockpicks. Find out which and do that instance with several characters. ;-)

Comment: I ran out of my Zephyrite Lockpicks two days ago and I'm saving my geodes to try to buy all of the amber fossil weapon recipes. I know the pain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't any trick. Per the [wiki](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Zephyrite_Lockpick), these are the ways you can get lockpicks:

One time:

- Complete living story sections [Prosperity's Mystery](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Prosperity%27s_Mystery) and [Cornered](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Cornered).
- Complete living story episode [Gates of Maguuma](http://wiki.guildwars2.com/wiki/Gates_of_Maguuma).

Repeatable:

- Kill enemies in Dry Top (rare drop).
- Loot from 10 piles of silky sand.
- Buy (with geodes) from Dusk or Gleam in Dry Top.

So, if you want lockpicks and don't want to spend geodes, you pretty much just have to run around Dry Top, completing events (for sand) and killing everything that moves.

The wiki's drop rate research indicates that you've got about a 2.3% chance of getting a lockpick from sand, so you'll average about 1 lockpick per 435 piles of silky sand.

Comment: I should also note that Silky Sand can be obtained from Locked Bandit Chests in the Silverwastes, and through reward chests for the Silverwastes PvP reward track.